# linux routing internal ip to use a specific external ip

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a application which connects to my server and receives an internal ip of 10.8.0.2 when it connects.

My server also has 10 external ip's and I want to route 10.8.0.2 to use one of them when accessing the internet.

10.8.0.2 -> should go out using 95.xx.122.63

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What distro or which firewall are you using?

Comment: ubuntu...no firewall atm

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are asking for snat:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 95.XX.122.63
```

Comment: It is likely he will also want the a rule to handle incoming traffic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shorewall one to one NAT appears to be what you are looking for.  http://www.shorewall.net/NAT.htm#One-to-one